# multicycle datapath vs single cycle datapath

Tags: cpu, computers, computer-architecture

I have a fairly simple question but have not been able to find a good answer googling.

I understand how pipelining works by having 1 cycle per step, each instruction takes 5 cycles  and they start on the second step of the previous instruction to finish the whole load faster.

Now from what I have read multicycle also has multiple steps per instruction but each instruction starts after the previous instruction has finished. With the benefit being for instructions that arent 5 steps long they do not have to go the whole 5 steps. Im assuming that we have to use the time of the slowest step for the clock cycle to allow all steps to works.

Now if this is correct I have calculated a small program that i was give as a homework problem where single cycle datapath is faster than the multicycle datapath. Is this normal ? or is there something about multicycle datapath that I have wrong ?

Comment: Your title (muti-cycle versus pipelined) does not match your question (single cycle versus multi-cycle).

Comment: Without any actual numbers it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

For a single cycle implementation it is to be expected that the clock frequency (determined by the longest delay through all access times and the logic) will be lower than for a multi-cycle implementation (where, presumambly, in each cycle only a part of the total data path of the single-cycle approach will be used).

If this does not hold for your implementation the interesting point is why.

Comment: Yes, my issue is that when calculating program execution time, the single cycle implementation time is faster than the multicycle time which seems strange.

In multicycle datapath each stage is one cycle, are those stages variable depending on the time of the stage ? or are they all the same time (eg slowest time) like in pipelined datapath ?

Comment: That depends on the implementation. How did you get the figures (cycles times and number of cycles)?